# How to Disable Spring's "typeMismatch" Exception? - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Basically I want to be able stop Spring from checking if my fields contain bad data, and instead let me handle all the validation and exceptions manually.

Suppose I have a class:

```
public class MyClass {

    int aNumber;
}
```

and a Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyValidator validator;

    public MyClass() {}

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(validator);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/postsomething", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView onPost(@ModelAttribute("myObject") MyClass myObject, BindingResult result) {

    validator.validate(myObject, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "postsomething";
    }

    return "redirect:success";
}
```

And finally a Validator:

```
public class MyValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        MyClass myObject = (MyClass) target;

        if (someCondition) {
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "aNumber", "error.myclass.anumber.null");
        }
    }
}
```

The point is that I only want an error message to be displayed once from MY validator if `someCondition` is true. But if I leave my port field in my form empty then it also displays Spring's error message for typeMismatch no matter what.

Can I disable the typeMismatch error, or should I go about all of this some other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer: declare members of your backing object as `String`.

The long answer: `typeMismatch` error occurs during binding and **before** validation. All user's data represented as `String` values (because this is what [ServletRequest.getParameter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) returns) and Spring tries to convert `String` value to the type of the field in your backing object. In your example, Spring will try to convert value of parameter `aNumber` to `int`. When you left field empty, then Spring tried to convert empty string to the `int` and of course it complains about mismatching types.

(This answer is still incomplete, because there is also different converters that Spring also tries to use, but I believe that you got the picture.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When you say "backing object" do you mean that I should use a DTO object that contains all Strings and then after validation, use the values in that DTO object to create my actual model object? I don't really want to change my model object to be all strings.

Comment: "When you say "backing object" do you mean that I should use a DTO object that contains all Strings", yes, exactly this.

Comment: I don't know why you are using old fashion validation and trying to disable auto conversion from `String` to `int`. I would rather write and use JSR303 validators and customize `typeMismatch` error messages for your needs (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722483/how-to-provide-a-message-of-my-choosing-on-form-validation-failure).

Comment: If you look through the edits and find the first draft of my question you will be able to see why. Basically I have a switch on my form which hides several of the fields. I only want those fields to be validated if the switch is turned on, otherwise I want them to be ignored. Here is a screenshot of my form. http://i.stack.imgur.com/cViE3.jpg The problem that I have is that if I put some invalid data in the Port field, and then turn the switch off and submit the form, the Port field throws the type mismatch exception and causes the form submit to fail.

Comment: As far I can see you are using JavaScript for switch, right? In this case you could disable unwanted fields (not only hide them). AFAIR disabled fields won't be send to the server and you won't have such errors. This is just one of the ideas about making server logic less complicated...

Comment: Yep that makes sense. You've given me a couple of good solutions so thanks :)